# Laravel/Ajax: highlight color inactive or active inside a function

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, function, if-statement

If you will see at the code below, under my `success: function (response)`, `getgroupstatus` will show either `active` or `inactive` depending on the row column.

[image: 1]

```
        function fetchgroup() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-group-configuration-group-list",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response){
                    var tbody="";
                    $.each(response.all_groups, function (key, group) {
                    tbody+=`
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">${group.group_name}</p>${group.group_description}</td>
                            <td>${group.group_type_name}</td>
                            <td>User List</td>
                            <td>${getgroupstatus(group.effective_start_datetime)}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" value="${group.group_id}" class="edit_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                                <button type="button" value="${group.group_id}" class="delete_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`;
                    });
                    
                    $('#main-group-list tbody').html(tbody)

                    //condition if status is shown as active or inactive
                    function getgroupstatus(status) {
                        var g_status = '';
                        if (status === null) {
                            g_status = 'Inactive'
                        } else {
                            g_status = 'Active'
                        } 
                        return g_status;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

This page of mine already has bootstrap so I am trying to have the `active` `text-success` and the `inactive` `text-danger`.

My problem is that I need to target the `<td>` outside the `getgroupstatus` to change the text color, how will I able to do this?

My thoughts are to give `<td>` a class like `status_color` and add to the if condition:

```
 if (status === null) {
    status_color = (code to change class text color)
    g_status = 'Inactive'
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: One option is to make your `getgroupstatus` return html like `<span class="text-success">Active</span>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify the function:

```js
    function fetchgroup() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-group-configuration-group-list",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response){
                    var tbody = response.all_groups.map(function (key, group) {
                    return `
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">${group.group_name}</p>${group.group_description}</td>
                            <td>${group.group_type_name}</td>
                            <td>User List</td>
                            <td class="${groupIsActive(group.effective_start_datetime) ? 'active' : 'inactive'}">
                                ${groupIsActive(group.effective_start_datetime) ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" value="${group.group_id}" class="edit_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                                <button type="button" value="${group.group_id}" class="delete_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`;
                    });
                    
                    $('#main-group-list tbody').html(tbody)

                    //condition if status is shown as active or inactive
                    function groupIsActive(status) {
                        return status === null;
                    }
                }
            });
```